# RGBA image not showing up with Pillow and tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter, python-imaging-library, python-3.7

I am trying to get a PNGA image to show up in my UI using Pillow and Tkinter. I'm on python 3.7.7 on macOS.

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

path = "path_to_image.png"
im = Image.open(path)
print(im.mode) # prints RGBA

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Karel")

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, bg="white", width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
img = Image.open(path)  # PIL solution
img = img.resize((250, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS) #The (250, 250) is (height, width)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) # convert to PhotoImage
image = canvas.create_image(150,150, image = img)

root.mainloop()
```

When I try this with images without an alpha channel, it works. Adding `img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img.convert("RGB"))` to remove the alpha channel makes a black box appear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The image:

[image]

Comment: I actually get an error when I put in the ```img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img.convert("RGB"))``` line. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: yup -- I don't get an error. I'm on Python 3.7.7 and Pillow 7.1.2 on macOS if that matters..

Comment: Yes, I think that matters, I ran it in python 3.7 and it worked.

Comment: Just to clarify, the image showed up, or the black box showed up?

Comment: I got a black box. I don't know what the error is, because I am not familiar with RGBA images

Comment: Why did you want to remove the alpha channel?

Comment: If you inspect the data of the image, all the (r, b, g) values are zero.   So removing the alpha channel will produce a black image.

Comment: I don't want to remove the alpha channel of the image. I want to get it to display properly but don't know how. The only way I can get anything to display at all is to remove the alpha channel from the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to do, but the issue is that all the information in your image is in the alpha (i.e. transparency) channel. I can demonstrate that by splitting out the R, G, B and A channels using **ImageMagick** in the Terminal like this and laying them out beside each other:

```
magick image.png -channel RGBA -separate -background none +smush 10  result.png
```

[image]

So, the Red, Green and Blue channels are all zero (i.e. black), and the alpha channel has white where it is transparent and you can see through to the RGB black, and it has black where it is transparent.

So, as regards your question, since all the info is in the alpha channel, you could take just the alpha channel as your image:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Karel")

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, bg="red", width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
path = "image.png"
img = Image.open(path).getchannel('A')   # Take just alpha channel
img = img.point(lambda a: 255-a)         # Invert black/white
img = img.resize((250, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
image = canvas.create_image(150,150, image = img)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

---

Note that you can easily install **ImageMagick** on macOS with **homebrew**:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

If you work with images, while you are there, get these packages too:

```
brew install pngcheck exiftool jhead
```

Comment: Thanks -- I didn't realize that the colors were inverted.